# Gigabyte to Megabyte

Tags: byte, data-conversion, megabyte

Is 1GB equal to 1000MB or 1024MB? Whenever I use google to convert it, I get 1000, but on multiple Q&A sites, I see 1024. Which is it?
Please do not say 'It depends on the situation'. I want a real answer.
[Google Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJgTE.png).
[Online Converter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oySec.png).

Comment: What if the answer is "it depends on the situation"?  What then?

Comment: http://puu.sh/mhbmT/38e1fe0092.png

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte

Answer (score 0):

A gigabyte is 10<sup>9</sup> byte = 1 000 000 000 byte. Which is shortended GB

The Giga-prefix means 10<sup>9</sup>, but has in the computer science-world meant 2<sup>30</sup>. Gibi- is a new prefix, that means 2^30. This is often shortened as GiB. IEC reccomends using gibibyte, for describing data-amounts, that are measued as a multiplication of 2<sup>30</sup> byte.

Edit: Although, as you point out in the image from wikipedia in the comments, JEDEC does recommend using the binary GB (2<sup>30</sup>), instead of the decimal.

Source:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_80000-13#Prefixes_for_binary_multiples